# Working with css floats in html2pdf

Tags: css, css-float, html2pdf

I'm using floats to position 2 divs beside each other.

```
<a href="printbox.php">print</a>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<style>
    #sidedish{
        float: left;

        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #maindish{
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #container{
        width: 304px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
<div id="sidedish"></div>
<div id="maindish"><div id="box">name</div></div>
</div>
<?php $_SESSION['boxes'] = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Here is what printbox do, it just renders the buffered data into a pdf, but somehow the floats that were set were lost in the process.

```
<?php require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php'); ?>
<?php
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
$html2pdf->writeHTML($_SESSION['boxes']);

$html2pdf->Output('random.pdf');
?>
```

It works fine on html:

[image]

but when I click on print it turns to this:

[image]

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Not find your mentioned problem. see http://jsfiddle.net/DYGvR/show/, test in chrome click mouse right, page print.

Comment: Are you using the browser to print? What does printbox.php do? I'm assuming he's clicking on the print link and printbox.php is somehow setting a width on the document.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Speaking from personal experiences, I would say styling the output of `HTML2PDF` is, at best, esoteric black magic science. The main reasons for this are:

- The class only supports a (relatively small) subset of CSS styles & selectors
- CSS compatibility is undocumented
- PDF is impossible to debug in relation to the HTML input

To be fair, this is not only the issue for `HTML2PDF` but [also for the `TCPDF` that `HTML2PDF` uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404236/216129).

It *might* be possible that `HTML2PDF`, being just an almost-zero-setup, quick & easy alternative interface for the `TCPDF`, cuts more CSS support off — but I'm sure that **even `TCPDF` wouldn't support `float` properly**.

The best workaround that you could use is to send your floating divs to the nineties:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="float"> ... </div></td>
        <td><div class="float"> ... </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could also hide this embarrassment from the public HTML:

```
<?php
    $isPdf = (/* condition that tells us we're outputting PDF */) ? true : false;
    if ($isPdf) {
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
    }
?>
<div class="float"> ... </div>
<?php
    if ($isPdf) { 
        echo "</td><td>";
    }
?>
<div class="float"> ... </div>
<?php
    if ($isPdf) {
        echo "</td></tr></table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful to me after I was ripping my hair out trying to figure out css workarounds. Back to the tables!! Also, fyi, I created a different copy of the page-in-question entirely, and if it was for PDF, direct there. If it wasn't, direct to the non-table.

Comment: I had the same problem. My solution was to use absolute positioning instead of floats, which worked well, but you need to set the container dimensions.

Comment: Actually, HTML2PDF supports far more CSS than TCPDF does, including absolute positioning, margins and paddings. Worth mentioning.

Answer (score 8):

You can see the quick documentation online in french here:
http://demo.html2pdf.fr/examples/pdf/about.pdf

('Les float ne sont gérés que pour la balise IMG')

= **Floats are only handled for img markups** by the class.

Handled css properties are also listed in the doc.