# Put elements from left and right side to the same line

Tags: html, css, django

I'm using `html2pdf` with my `Django project` in order to create some PDF files and I get an HTML problem.

I would like to put two elements situated on the same line but the first one is located into the right side and the other one to the left side.

My script looks like :

```
<html>
    <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/BC_base.css' %}"/>

    <style>

        body {
                font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
                /*text-align: justify;*/
                list-style-type: none;
            }

        .alignleft {
                float: left;
                border-right : 100px;
            }
        .alignright {
                float: right;
                border-left: 100px;
            }

        .title {
                border-top: 150px;
                font-size: 7;
        }

        {% block style %}
                @page {
                size: landscape;
                }

        {%endblock%} 
    </style>

    </head>

        <h2 class = "title" align="center" > ATTESTATION DE RECENSEMENT </align> </h2>

        <div id="textbox">
            <p class="alignleft">Le maire de la commune <br />de {{mairie.city}}</p>
            <p class="alignright">Imprimé n° {{ar.id}}<br/> Loi n° ... du XX XX XXXX</p>
        </div>
```

But I don't overcome to put `alignleft` and `alignright` classes on the same line.

I'm using the library `html2pdf` to do that so all CSS command are not take account.

Thank you if you have an idea ?

**EDIT :**

This is what I'm getting with @ShivkumarKondi answer :

[image]

Comment: you are using p element and its block element which takes full width.so change its display type or use some other inline element

Comment: By which can of elements I could change `<p>` ? `<ul>` ? I'm really new with html

Comment: Can you modify css properties? If so, you can try with adding `display: inline-block` on both `.alignleft` and `.alignright`

Comment: @Treeindev It doesn't work ^^ I have already tried this

Comment: can you let me know what you what with some screen shot, and try this codepin to edit your html http://codepen.io/shivk/pen/LxaeyB

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi I tried your css file and I posted an edit in my question with the result.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776391/working-with-css-floats-in-html2pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776391/working-with-css-floats-in-html2pdf) answer, the problem is html2pdf itself, because it doesn't render css floats like it should.

Try wrapping your html with a `<table>`. Like this:

```css
#upp {
  width: 100%;
  /*background:red;*/
}
.alignleft,
.alignright {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
.alignleft {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.alignright {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id="upp">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="alignleft">Le maire de la commune <br />de {{mairie.city}}</p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right">
       <p class="alignright">Imprimé n° {{ar.id}}<br/> Loi n° ... du XX XX XXXX</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you it works pretty well. I just have to modify `border-right` and `border-left` spaces because it doesn't seem to work but I get both elements to each side

Comment: Do you know how I can fit both elements to the center with landscape format ? `border-left` and `border-right` don't seem to work

Comment: Fit to the center? What do you mean?

Comment: I would like to add a space between right border and right element for example. I tried `border-right` or `padding-right` but doesn't seem work with `html2pdf`

Comment: Did you set padding-left: 100px on .alignleft and padding-right: 100px on .alignright?

Comment: Yes and with landscape format I think there's a problem :/

Comment: It should work. Maybe is another problem with html2pdf

Comment: I think it's another problem but I overcame to solve it using some arrays with several cells in order to shift elements :)

Answer (score 0):

Both have to float left and you have to apply them a display property to each one. Probably display: inline.

Answer (score 0):

Normal float property is enough here to the task,which gives you below output

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
  border-right : 100px;
  background:red;



}
.alignright {
  float: right;
  border-left: 100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox">
  <p class="alignleft">Le maire de la commune <br />de {{mairie.city}}</p>
   <p class="alignright">Imprimé n° {{ar.id}}<br/> Loi n° ... du XX XX XXXX</p>
</div>
```

**update :**

In your case floats are not working in html2pdf ,so I would recommend to go for bootstrap grid system. Just give a try here also

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div class="row" style="background:grey;">
  <div class="col-xs-3">content left</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3" style="text-align:right;">content right</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Don't forget I'm working on landscape format ! Your example seems to work on portrait format with html. But I'm using landscape format and `html2pdf`. Your answer is exactly my script in the question

Comment: @Valentin Yeah I don't know Why it didn't work, just give a try for bootstrap too

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `flex`?

```css
.outter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div>LEFT</div>
  <div>RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get an error in my script (`pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')`) with your method : `Selector name or qualifier expected:: (u'', u'/\n\n        \n\n       ')`

Comment: @Valentin I'm sorry. I completely missed the PDF part.