# $pdf->SetFont sets the font to whole page

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

$pdf->SetFont sets the font to entire page but i want this font to be affected only to span tag.

```
require_once('../tcpdf.php');       
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$fruit=$pdf->AddFont('fruit');
$html='<span '.$pdf->SetFont($fruit['family']).'>my text in bold</span>This isnormal';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Check out this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990216/html-rendering-with-tcpdfphp


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990216/html-rendering-with-tcpdfphp

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set the font for each cases. For example

```
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 16);
// now time s font will applied for the following cell
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, 'Table Of Content', 0, 'C', 0, 1, '', '', true, 0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
// This will override the time s font applied before and apply helvetica as the new font
```

In your case as you are passing an html you can write inline style  to the span and get it applied . // Please try this and see if it has any effect

```
$html='<span style="font-weight:bold" '.$pdf->SetFont($fruit['family']).'>my text in bold</span>This isnormal';
```

Comment: even after using $pdf->setFont inside span tag whole document is reflecting with same font..i want the font only to be reflected in span tag

Comment: You will get answer to  your question by referring these 2 links. 
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf //this is the pdf generated result of the php file(example_006.phps)
Dont forget that you can add inline style.