# Trying to find list of supported CSS for TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to find the list of supported CSS for TCPDF - supposedly there's a list in here: getHtmlDomArray(), but I cannot find this function in any of the files.

Has it been updated recently? I'm trying to add margins on every div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395171/why-does-tcpdf-ignore-my-inline-css

Comment: I saw that, but the documentation page isn't there anymore, and that was several months ago.

Answer (score 6):

Margin and padding doesn't work with TCPDF.

You can see two links :

- [Why does TCPDF ignore my inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395171/why-does-tcpdf-ignore-my-inline-css)

But I don't now if the list is complet. (Edit) His link doesn't work but the new link is here : [TCPDF doc](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html)

And this one :

- [TCPDF not render all CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404095/tcpdf-not-render-all-css-properties)

he suggests to take [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) if you need convert html to pdf but I never use.

I have try to do something with tcpdf and I think that it's not the better for html but the multicell() is very good.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, TCPDF supports following attributes

- color
- background-color
- font-size
- font-weight
- font-family
- text-align
- text-transform
- width
- height
- border

Does not supported margin, padding, etc attributes of CSS. If you want to use CSS attributes then you have define in . Example is given below.

```
// define some HTML content with style
$html = <<<EOF
<!-- EXAMPLE OF CSS STYLE -->
<style>
    h1 {
        color: navy;
        font-family: times;
        font-size: 24pt;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    p.first {
        color: #003300;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    p.first span {
        color: #006600;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    p#second {
        color: rgb(00,63,127);
        font-family: times;
        font-size: 12pt;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    p#second > span {
        background-color: #FFFFAA;
    }
    table.first {
        color: #003300;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 8pt;
        border-left: 3px solid red;
        border-right: 3px solid #FF00FF;
        border-top: 3px solid green;
        border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
        background-color: #ccffcc;
    }
    td {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        background-color: #ffffee;
    }
    td.second {
        border: 2px dashed green;
    }
    div.test {
        color: #CC0000;
        background-color: #FFFF66;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border-style: solid solid solid solid;
        border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border-color: green #FF00FF blue red;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .lowercase {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    .uppercase {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .capitalize {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>

<h1 class="title">Example of <i style="color:#990000">XHTML + CSS</i></h1>

<p class="first">Example of paragraph with class selector. <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed imperdiet lectus. Phasellus quis velit velit, non condimentum quam. Sed neque urna, ultrices ac volutpat vel, laoreet vitae augue. Sed vel velit erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras eget velit nulla, eu sagittis elit. Nunc ac arcu est, in lobortis tellus. Praesent condimentum rhoncus sodales. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin porta eros pharetra enim tincidunt dignissim nec vel dolor. Cras sapien elit, ornare ac dignissim eu, ultricies ac eros. Maecenas augue magna, ultrices a congue in, mollis eu nulla. Nunc venenatis massa at est eleifend faucibus. Vivamus sed risus lectus, nec interdum nunc.</span></p>

<p id="second">Example of paragraph with ID selector. <span>Fusce et felis vitae diam lobortis sollicitudin. Aenean tincidunt accumsan nisi, id vehicula quam laoreet elementum. Phasellus egestas interdum erat, et viverra ipsum ultricies ac. Praesent sagittis augue at augue volutpat eleifend. Cras nec orci neque. Mauris bibendum posuere blandit. Donec feugiat mollis dui sit amet pellentesque. Sed a enim justo. Donec tincidunt, nisl eget elementum aliquam, odio ipsum ultrices quam, eu porttitor ligula urna at lorem. Donec varius, eros et convallis laoreet, ligula tellus consequat felis, ut ornare metus tellus sodales velit. Duis sed diam ante. Ut rutrum malesuada massa, vitae consectetur ipsum rhoncus sed. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque a congue massa.</span></p>

<div class="test">example of DIV with border and fill.
<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br /><span class="lowercase">text-transform <b>LOWERCASE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
<br /><span class="uppercase">text-transform <b>uppercase</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
<br /><span class="capitalize">text-transform <b>cAPITALIZE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>

<br />

<table class="first" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="6">
 <tr>
  <td width="30" align="center"><b>No.</b></td>
  <td width="140" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><b>XXXX</b></td>
  <td width="140" align="center"><b>XXXX</b></td>
  <td width="80" align="center"> <b>XXXX</b></td>
  <td width="80" align="center"><b>XXXX</b></td>
  <td width="45" align="center"><b>XXXX</b></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="30" align="center">1.</td>
  <td width="140" rowspan="6" class="second">XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="140">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX</td>
  <td align="center" width="45">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="30" align="center" rowspan="3">2.</td>
  <td width="140" rowspan="3">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td align="center" width="45">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td align="center" width="45">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="80" rowspan="2" >XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td align="center" width="45">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="30" align="center">3.</td>
  <td width="140">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td align="center" width="45">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFF80">
  <td width="30" align="center">4.</td>
  <td width="140" bgcolor="#00CC00" color="#FFFF00">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td width="80">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
  <td align="center" width="45">XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
 </tr>
</table>
EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
```

I hope, this would be helpful to you.